# web3.auth integration to Login page with Solana wallet

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, react-native

I'm making a login page for my dapp, and I think I will build on Solana chain.

And I wonder how I can add web3.auth in the page.

I'm using react-native, not sure what to do with this step web3.auth quick start:

```
await web3auth.login({
  loginProvider: LoginProvider.GOOGLE,
  redirectUrl: resolvedRedirectUrl,
});
```

Comment: https://web3auth.io/docs/examples?product=Plug%20and%20Play&sdk=Plug%20and%20Play%20React%20Native%20SDK